# android Deep linking with adds

Tags: android, deep-linking

How to open specific page of app on clicking notification of that app in android ?

I have a android app.

I am also creating *Notification* for that.

On clicking that notification it opens the app home page. But i want to open specific page of that app.

*How to do that ?*

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of `PendingIntent` where you can pass a particular `Activity` where you want to redirect on notification tap.

Refer the developer documentation for more [info](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Comment: am getting add in my application.i want a specific page of another application when i click on that add.